Spotipy accessing user's Playlist : Access to localhost was denied (http error 403)
type hereimport os
import spotipy
from flask import Flask, session, redirect, url_for,request
from dotenv import load_dotenv

from spotipy import Spotify
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth
from spotipy.cache_handler import FlaskSessionCacheHandler

load_dotenv()

# creates flask app and stores it in variable
app = Flask(__name__)
# can make a permanent key later
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.urandom(64)
client_id = os.getenv("CLIENT_ID")
client_secret = os.getenv("CLIENT_SECRET")

redirect_uri = "http://localhost:5000/callback"

# mention scopes of the project
scope = 'playlist-read-private'

# allow spotipy to store access token in flask session
cache_handler = FlaskSessionCacheHandler(session)
# authentication manager
sp_oauth = SpotifyOAuth(
    client_id=client_id,
    client_secret=client_secret,
    redirect_uri=redirect_uri,
    scope=scope,
    cache_handler= cache_handler,
    show_dialog = True
)

# create instance of spotify client, call methods using up to get data
sp = Spotify(auth_manager=sp_oauth)

# end point
@app.route('/')
def home():
    # check if logged in already or not
    # sp_ouath method validate_token checks if we have a valid token
    # while get_cached_token method returns token  from flask session

    if not sp_oauth.validate_token(cache_handler.get_cached_token()):
        # if we don't then ask for login/token
        auth_url = sp_oauth.get_authorize_url()
        return redirect(auth_url)
    return redirect(url_for('get_playlists'))

# refreshes token on behalf of user
@app.route('/callback')
def callback():
    sp_oauth.get_access_token(request.args['code'])
    return redirect(url_for('get_playlists'))


@app.route('/get_playlists')
def get_playlists():
    # check if token is valid just incase
    if not sp_oauth.validate_token(cache_handler.get_cached_token()):
        auth_url = sp_oauth.get_authorize_url()
        return redirect(auth_url)

    playlists = sp.current_user_playlists()
    playlists_info = [(pl['name'], pl['external_url']['spotify']) for pl in playlists['items']]
    playlists_html = '<br>'.join([f'{name}: {url}' for name, url in playlists_info])

    return playlists_html

# log out
@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session.clear()
    return redirect(url_for('home'))

# run flask app when file is run
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

I'm able to login with my spotify account but when agreeing to connect I'm encountering " Access to localhost was deniedYou don't have authorization to view this page.
HTTP ERROR 403"
Tried Creating new app, changed browser (from chrome to safari), cleared cookies. I also used spotify's api without spotipy and it worked (top 10 tracks of an artist), if this info helps in any way.

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.


Spotipy, the Python library for Spotify's Web API, simplifies handling OAuth2 authentication by abstracting much of the complexity involved in managing the authentication flow, tokens, and token refresh.

Spotipy's built-in OAuth flow alleviates the need for manual callback handling and code decoding typically seen in other environments like using Express with Node.js:
Spotipy’s design abstracts these steps into a more straightforward, high-level API, greatly simplifying the developer's workload when creating applications that interact with Spotify’s Web API.
This is why, in demo Python code using Spotipy, you don't see explicit callback handling or code decoding like you might in an Express application.
Demo
demo.py
import spotipy
from flask import Flask, redirect, session, url_for
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth
from spotipy import cache_handler
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

# Set your Spotify API credentials as environment variables, it will pick by spotipy API
client_id = os.getenv("CLIENT_ID")
if client_id is not None:
    os.environ["SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID"] = client_id
else:
    print("CLIENT_ID environment variable is not set.")

client_secret = os.getenv("CLIENT_SECRET")
if client_secret is not None:
    os.environ["SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET"] = client_secret
else:
    print("CLIENT_SECRET environment variable is not set.")

# Set your redirect URI
os.environ["SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI"] = "http://localhost:3000/callback"

# Define the required OAuth scope
oAuthscope = "playlist-read-private"

# Initialize the cache handler and auth manager for Spotipy
Sp_Cache = cache_handler.CacheFileHandler()
auth_manager = spotipy.SpotifyOAuth(scope=oAuthscope, cache_handler=Sp_Cache)
sp_oauth = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=auth_manager)

# Ensure the Flask application has a secret key for secure sessions
app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return redirect(url_for('get_playlists'))

@app.route('/get_playlists')
def get_playlists():
    playlists = sp_oauth.current_user_playlists()
    playlists_info = [(pl['name'], pl['external_urls']['spotify']) for pl in playlists['items']]
    playlists_html = '<br>'.join([f'{name}: {url}' for name, url in playlists_info])
    return playlists_html

@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    # Clearing the Flask session for logging out
    session.clear()
    return redirect(url_for('home'))

# run flask app when file is run
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

Result

